# Can someone check my work on this area problem?

Tags: calculus, integration, area

If I'm correct, just let me know. If I'm not, please show me where I've messed it up.

Find the area of the region bounded by the curves:

$$ x = 4 - y^2, \; x = y^2 - 4 $$

Putting them in a $y = \cdots$ format I get:

$$ y = \sqrt{-x+4}, \; y = \sqrt{x + 4} $$

I drew the graph and realized that it is symmetrical so I did the following integral:

$$ 2 \int_0^4 \sqrt{-x+4}\;\mathrm{d}x $$

Since I am only integrating half of the equation, I have to double the integral.

Then integrating, I do a $u$-sub:

$$ u = x+4, \; \mathrm{d}u = \mathrm{d}x $$

Which changes my bounds, so my new integral looks like:

$$ 2 \int_4^8 u^\frac{1}{2}\;\mathrm{d}u $$

Integrating leaves me with (fixed mixed up denominator)

$$ 2 \left[\frac{u^{3/2}}{3/2}\right]_4^8$$

Leaving me with:

$$ \left(\frac{4}{3}\right)\left[u^{3/2}\right]_4^8 $$

Comment: The sub $u=x+4$ is for the other integral, not the one you displayed on the line indented. (That shouldn't matter if both are the same by symmetry.) However the antiderivative of $u^{1/2}$ is not what you have written, there should be $3/2$ in the denominator.

Comment: It seems that I messed up the fraction, but I multiplied it through correctly on the step under it. Does that one look correct? I think the approximate answer is around 50?

Comment: ConfusingCalc -- I have looked at things more carefully and some of it was too long for a comment; see answer below. Your set-up seems off (to me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think by going with trying to solve for $y$ in terms of $x$ you got the wrong description. Since the $y$ appears squared in both equations there should be at least cases of $+$ or $-$ signs in front of the radicals involved, and a sketch shows there are four little regions.

But if you keep things as $x=4-y^2$ and $x=-(4-y^2)$ as initially given, you can double the integral of $4-y^2$ for $y$ going from $-2$ to $2$ (draw a sketch to see this is half the area of the finite region between the two parabolas).

When I did this I got $32/3$ which after doubling gives $64/3 \approx 21.33$ for the total area.

Comment: You are correct, since it is a square root I forgot to keep in mind that it is + or -. However, I think that my answer still equates to yours (I made a mistake when I first mentioned my answer): $2* [\frac{4}{3}(8)^\frac{3}{2} - \frac{4}{3}(4)^\frac{3}{2}]$ == $ 2* [30.16 - 19.50] $ = $21.32$. Thanks for the confirmation!

Comment: @ConfusingCalc Yes your approach also works if you double each side to account for the negative radical part. Nice when two ways give the same answer. :-)

Comment: I got lucky :) you were right that I didn't realize I only had half of it graphed! Appreciate your help